# Probability of winning or tying golf match based on status of the match

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A golf match consists of 18 independent holes worth 1 point. If a player wins a hole outright they get 1 point, if the hole is tied, each player gets .5 points. The match is over when one player has accumulated at least 9.5 points, which can occur before the 18th hole.

**Given that Player A leads or trails by N points with X holes left to play, and player A has probability of winning a hole W, tying a hole T, and losing a hole L (these sum to 1), how can you calculate player A's probability of winning the match, or that the match ends in a tie?**

Example: Player A leads by 1 point with 5 holes to play (14th hole is next), with probabilities of hole outcomes (W = .29, T = .42, L = .29)

---

So far, here is what I'm thinking on the example problem above...

p(win match) = p(win match on 14) + p(win match on 15) + p(win match on 16) + p(win match on 17) + p(win match on 18)

p(win match on 14) = 0 since the largest lead that could be accumulated is 2 with 4 left to play

p(win match on 15) = 0 since the largest lead that could be accumulated is 3 with 3 left to play

p(win match on 16) = p(having 3 point lead going into 16) * p(W + T) + p(having 2 point lead going into 16) * p(W)

p(having 3 point lead going into 16) = p(W)^2 (have to win twice to get to this point)

p(having 2 point lead going into 16) = 2 * p(W)*p(T) (have to win and tie to get to this point)

so p(win match on 16) = p(W)^2 * p(W + T) + 2 * p(W)*p(T) * p(T)

p(win match on 17) = p(having 2 point lead going into 17) * p(W + T) + p(having 1 point lead going into 17) * p(W)

p(having 2 point lead going into 17) = 3 * p(W)*p(T)^2 + 3 * p(L)*p(W)^2 (these are only two ways to gain 1 point over span of 3 holes)

p(having 1 point lead going into 16) = 3 * p(T)^3 + 3 * p(W)*p(L)*P(T) (these are only two ways to gain 0 points over span of 3 holes)

so p(win match on 17) = (3 * p(W)*p(T)^2 + 3 * p(L)*p(W)^2) * p(W + T) + (3 * p(T)^3 + 3 * p(W)*p(L)*P(T)) * P(W)

similar logic applies to 18. Player must be up 1 and win or tie, or be up 0 and win.

**Is there a general formula I can use to calculate win or tie probabilities given any status of the match?**

Comment: This is very close to the first probability question ever analyzed. Wikipedia sez, The mathematical methods of probability arose in the investigations first of Gerolamo Cardano in the 1560s (not published until 100 years later), and then in the correspondence Pierre de Fermat and Blaise Pascal (1654) on such questions as the fair division of the stake in an interrupted game of chance. Christiaan Huygens (1657) gave a comprehensive treatment of the subject.[3][2]: 296–316 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to enumerate all possibilities, it is much simpler and less error-prone to use recursive equations.  Let $p(N,X)$ be the probability that player $A$ wins, given current state $(N,X)$.  We have $p(N,X)=1$ if $N \ge 9.5$ and $p(N,X)=0$ if $N \le -9.5$.  By conditioning on the next hole, we obtain recursion
$$p(N,X) = p(N+1,X-1) \mathbb{P}(W) + p(N,X-1) \mathbb{P}(T) + p(N-1,X-1) \mathbb{P}(L).$$

Comment: This is extremely helpful in thinking about the problem, but I have an issue implementing a recursive solution because it still effectively enumerates all the possible options and can lead to a stack overflow in my program. Is there another approach that provides a non-recursive formula?

Comment: For instance, if player A already has 7 points, the probability of winning in 5 holes is p(score 1.5 points in next 4 holes)*P(W) + p(score 2 points in next 4 holes)(P(W)+P(T)). Can I use a combination/permutation formula to calculate the "score _ points in _ holes" part? The issue I run into is it can be a combination of wins and ties that contribute different amounts of points.

Comment: For implementing the recursion, you should either use memoization or order your computations so you compute lower values of $X$ first.

Comment: Thank you! I will be able to use memoization. There are only 180 possible starting conditions.